# How to work with multi-client applications in a git repository?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

How can I manage my application versions with git when I have more than one client that has diferent modules, reports and etc?
Should I create one repo for each client?
Creating branchs for each client is wrong cause branches are supposed to be merged back to master, right?

Conclusions:

-> Is wrong to use branchs to manage different versions of your system.

Comment: How different are the different client versions of your application? Are they really that different that you would consider distinct repos? Branches don't necessarily need to be merged back.

Comment: Its totally wrong to say that branches are needed to merge back in master, for e.g. gh-pages branches

Comment: The concept of a branch is that it'S gonna be merged back to create a new tag. That's what I think, thus, it's wrong to branch somenthing that's supposed to be a final version.

Comment: @GerarRyan the application have tons of modifications in each client, but is has the same core wich reveive tons os updgrades every week. Some of those modification are made for one client and released for the others, and some are build only for a specific client.

Comment: @AndreDuarte Your assumptions are wrong. Many repositories have long-standing branches with different modifications which are never going to be merged into master.

Comment: @HolgerJust even if there is many repositories, this is wrong. Check this [link](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Branchs, trunks were created to support the development of a new tag. If my assumptions about this subject are wrong, please provide me more info.

Comment: You should look at trunk-based development to see a very good example where you have long-standing branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to propose what I think are two possible answers, neither of which really answer the exact question that you're asking; but I think that the way that you've asked the question could lead potential answers down a particular path. It's not a problem with the way the question is asked, more the things that we're (at least I am) drawn to when reading it.

**Proposal 1**

Have distinct repositories per module of your application. As you have hinted in the comments to the question, the "core" receives a lot of commits each week. Maybe that could be one repo (or several, nobody can really say without looking at your code for a while). Each optional module could also have its own repo. Then you could have an additional repo for code that supports "release engineering" related activities, like packaging the application in different ways for different clients: different modules/configurations for different clients.

**Proposal 2**

If the idea of splitting modules up like in proposal 1 sounds impossible (coupling too tightly or otherwise), then I would still try to pull out configurations as data that gets fed to whatever your build system is. Ideally you probably don't want to maintain a different version of your code for each client, that sounds like a maintenance nightmare. This way you have your canonical version of your code, and you just build it differently for each client. You shouldn't have to update in several different branches when you find a bug in something on one version.

There are likely many other ways to approach this, better or worse. A combination of the two could also work well I think.